# PHP: mimicking explode with regex

Tags: php, regex

I want to mimic the explode function with regex.
For example: given the string: "/home/index/6"
I want to be able to get an array from this string: ["home", "index", "6"]
without using the function explode.

I had tried this code:

```
<?php

$regex = "(/|(/([a-zA-Z]+))+)";

$url = $_GET["url"];

if(preg_match("@" . $regex . "@", $url, $matches)) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($matches);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

But it didn't work.
Can someone help me with this? thanks :)

Comment: Why you don't want to use explode()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it but to have several results, you need to use `preg_match_all`. The best way to mimick explode without using `preg_split` is probably to use the `\G` anchor that ensures that all matches will be consecutive:

```
$regex = '~(?:\A|\G/)\K[^/]*~';

if (preg_match_all($regex, $url, $matches)) { 
    print_r($matches[0]);
```

To be clear, there is no advantage to use something else than `explode` that is from far the fastest way, I assume that you want to do this as an exercise.

Comment: why use ?? Instead of ? In \A/??

Comment: @walidtoumi: the goal is to obtain an empty result (as with explode) when the string begins with a leading slash. In this case the `??` quantifier forces to not match the slash and to match the empty string before the slash.

Comment: @walidtoumi: but it is useless since a simple `\A` does the same. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Actually, no. I'm building a MVC framework (mainly for my own website) and i want the user to be able to provide a regex for a route.

Answer (score 1):

```
([^\/]+)
```

You can try this.use `search` instead of `match`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/wQ1oW3/11

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function to perform a global regex match.

```
<?php
$data = "/home/index/6";
$regex = '~(?<=/).*?(?=/|$)~';
preg_match_all($regex, $data, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => home
            [1] => index
            [2] => 6
        )
)
```

Comment: it's a directory path. So it must starts with an / symbol.

Comment: this `[^\/]*(?=\/|$)` would do the job.